# Will multiple network connections from NAS / Computer to switch increase transfer speeds

Tags: networking, nas, 10gbit

I have a NAS with 4 drives in. Each drive can sustain around 140MB/s read speed giving a total (completely theoretical*) read speed of around 4.5 Gbps. My NAS is connected to my Gigabyte switch with 1 connection. My computer is also connected to the same switch with 1 Gbps connection.

My NAS does have a second Gbps interface. My question is if I connect this to the same switch will the total (theoretical) transfer speed from my NAS to the network go from 1Gbps to 2Gbps? I've always thought that this second connection is for redundancy or to connect to another network but now I am wondering if I can increase network speeds with it.

My NAS (Netgear ReadyNas 314) has a "New Bond" option on the ethernet settings menu. This looks promising!

[image]

Obviously this will only help if my computer has a faster connection as well so, in a similar way, would turning on my roughly 300Mbps wifi connection on my desktop increase my total network speed from 1Gbps to ~1.3Gbps?
(This would just be a test really. I'd most likely update the computer and switch to 10 Gbps).

*I realise that multiplying the access speed of 1 drive by the total number of drives is very very optimistic. As the NAS provides redundancy it would seem the absolute maximum speed would be reading from 2 discs at a time but most likely it'll just be the read speed of 1 disk that is more realistic.

Comment: The switch and nas would need to support link aggregation groups (LAGs). Most pre-built consumer NAS boxes have bottlenecks at the motherboard, or system bus. So this may not work as expected, a home built nas, or higher end box probably wouldn't have this problem. What's the make / model of your nas?

Comment: It's a netgear readynas 314. Added details to the question.

Comment: Is the 140 megabytes per sec from a single drive, or raid array? Are these bays actually populated with sata-III drives? A single sata-III drive should have real world transfer speeds well above +3Gbps. What are your avg read/write speeds for this unit JBOD vs r.a.i.d array?

Comment: I got the 140MBs from a review of the drive. They are not particularly new and only spin at 5400 rpm. The SATA speed is well above that but this is the real world read speed.